# Focus last ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `CustomListBox` inherited from `System.Windows.Controls.ListBox`. I want it to control keyboard focus.

Now, when focus enters `ListBox`, it goes to first item. I want it to be on last element.

So, how to implement it in inherited class?
What `ListBox` methods should I override? And how to move keyboard focus in code?

UPD: I don't want to select last item. Just set focus.